# Are Multiple Lambda callbacks possible

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, serverless

I have a lambda/server less function that is going to perform several API calls that will take some time. I want to update the user on the front end as each task completed (progress bar style) but the only way I'm aware of to send information back is the callback function, which I can only use once at the end of the whole process.

Is there a way of sending multiple callbacks?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many ways to approach this. Can you post some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can call AWS Lambda callback only once.
So you can receive result only once: when it is done or failed.

Here is wha related [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html) says:

> When the callback is called, AWS Lambda continues the Lambda function
>   invocation until the event loop is empty.

It means that after callback called - you will receive the response. However, function can finish its work later, but you will not be able to get any new data from function anymore.

Moreover, it is very important to remember, that when you call Lambda you actually make a call to **stateless** container. So it is impossible to save the state and then read it with the next call. You should never save and rely on any data saved inside of that container.

Possible solution for you can be splitting your job to few chunks and send each chunk for processing separately. Then, upon receiving responses about successful processing of the chunk you can update progress bar.